# A* pathfiinding algorithm cant find 2nd target

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

i have a program which i want to find the distance between a target, then to an end point one after another. it can find the first target but not the second one.

the code finds the target, but then begins to search in random directions, like dijkstra's. if it visits the end node it somply overwrites it as if it was an empty node. it also will not visit any node which had previously been inspected in the first step of the algorithm. any help would be much appreciated!

Code for the algorithm here:

```
def A_Star_algorithm(draw, grid, start, end, target_check, target):

    if not target:
        count = 0
        open_set = PriorityQueue()
        open_set.put((0, count, start))
        came_from = {}
        g_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        g_score[start] = 0
        f_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        f_score[start] = h(start.get_pos(), end.get_pos())
        
        open_set_hash = {start}
        
        while not open_set.empty():
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
            current = open_set.get()[2]
            open_set_hash.remove(current)
            
            if current == end:
                reconstruct_path(came_from, end, draw, start)
                end.make_end()
                return True
            for neighbor in current.neighbors:
                temp_g_score = g_score[current] + 1
                
                if temp_g_score < g_score[neighbor]:
                    came_from[neighbor] = current
                    g_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score
                    f_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score + h(neighbor.get_pos(), end.get_pos())
                    if neighbor not in open_set_hash:
                        count += 1
                        open_set.put((f_score[neighbor], count, neighbor))
                        open_set_hash.add(neighbor)
                        neighbor.make_open()
            draw()
            if current != start:
                current.make_closed()
                
                
                
    elif target:
        count = 0
        open_set = PriorityQueue()
        open_set.put((0, count, start))
        came_from = {}
        g_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        g_score[start] = 0
        f_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        f_score[start] = h(start.get_pos(), target.get_pos())

        open_set_hash = {start}
        
        while not open_set.empty():
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
            current = open_set.get()[2]
            open_set_hash.remove(current)

            if current == target:
                reconstruct_path(came_from, target, draw, start)
                target.make_target()
                open_set.queue.clear()
                
            for neighbor in current.neighbors:
                temp_g_score = g_score[current] + 1

                if temp_g_score < g_score[neighbor]:
                    came_from[neighbor] = current
                    g_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score
                    f_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score + h(neighbor.get_pos(), target.get_pos())
                    if neighbor not in open_set_hash:
                        count += 1
                        open_set.put((f_score[neighbor], count, neighbor))
                        open_set_hash.add(neighbor)
                        neighbor.make_open()
            draw()
            if current != start:
                current.make_closed()
                
        count = 0
        open_set = PriorityQueue()
        open_set.put((0, count, target))
        came_from = {}
        g_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        g_score[target] = 0
        f_score = {node: float("inf") for row in grid for node in row}
        f_score[target] = h(target.get_pos(), end.get_pos())
        open_set_hash.clear()
        open_set_hash = {target}
        
        while not open_set.empty():
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
            current = open_set.get()[2]
            open_set_hash.remove(current2)
            
            if current == end:
                reconstruct_path(came_from, end, draw, target)
                end.make_end()
                return True
            for neighbor in current.neighbors:
                temp_g_score = g_score[current2] + 1

                if temp_g_score < g_score[neighbor]:
                    came_from[neighbor] = current2
                    g_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score
                    f_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score + h(neighbor.get_pos(), end.get_pos())
                    if neighbor not in open_set_hash:
                        count += 1
                        open_set.put((f_score[neighbor], count, neighbor))
                        open_set_hash.add(neighbor)
                        neighbor.make_open()
            draw()
            if current != target:
                current.make_closed()
```

```
return False
```